# Chinese Visa Form Question

Tags: visas, tourist-visas

I am trying to apply for a Chinese tourist visa. I was born abroad in country A but acquired US citizenship at birth through one of my parents. I also had A's passport that was acquired when I was a little kid. (It was later cancelled when I legally "acquired" the US citizenship.) In the application form, do I note in my application that I was a former national for A?

Comment: Yes if they ask for that

Comment: The newer forms are getting quite intrusive and IIRC do ask for current and former nationality(s), so you should answer truthfully.

Comment: If you were a US citizen at birth, then you did not later legally acquire US citizenship. You might have later acquired a US passport or other proof of US citizenship, but that is not an acquisition of US citizenship.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with hypotheticals makes it difficult to answer... For example, if country "A" is China, then yeah, you have to disclose that. Besides this particular case, the general rule is, if there is a question on the form, you answer it. If there isn't, you don't volunteer any information.

So check the form: is there a question about former citizenships? If yes, say so, if not, you don't even have a space to write down this piece of information anyway.

**EDIT**

I just checked and the form (from the Chinese Visa Center in Paris) asks this:

[image: ID Details]

1.6 Current Citizenship vs 1.7 Birth Citizenship if different.

So yeah, you need to give both.

Comment: The English version from the Los Angeles consulate http://losangeles.china-consulate.org/eng/visa/forms/P020130831026095240145.pdf says "1.6 Current nationality(ies)" and "1.7 Former nationality(ies)," which is even more explicit.

Comment: The Chinese there also says "1.6 Current nationality(ies)" and "1.7 Former nationality(ies),"

Comment: Actually the OP is a US citizen by birth, so technically on the French language version they wouldn't need to list anything else.

Comment: Actually the OP still would have to: the French text is a bad translation. The Chinese text on the form says "Former Citizenship(s)" (which is in line with the American version)). And I bet that's the version that matters to the Chinese authorities. If they saw a birth place outside the US, they WOULD ask about any former citizenship.

Answer (score 2):

You were a dual citizen: a US citizen at birth and a citizen of the country in which you were born. At some point, you relinquished the latter (as used to be required of born abroad US citizens when they reached the age of 18).

However, that visa application form is not asking about dual nationality: you can correctly respond to question 1.6, nationality, USA, and leave 1.7 blank, unanswered.